# Azure get subscription cost using Ruby

Tags: ruby, azure, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to get the Azure subscription cost using Ruby? I tied `Azure::Armrest` but it doesn't provide the total cost for subscription.

I can't find any article explaining how to get cost of subscription.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices

Comment: I mean the current usage cost of a subscription not the service cost

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/